# Rails 3.2 Nginx-Unicorn 413 Request Entity too large

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, http-status-code-413

I'm running a Rails 3.2 app on an nginx-unicorn set up and when I try to upload a file (using dropzonejs) that's 1MB or larger I get a "413 Request Entity too large" error. I've tried changing the nginx.conf file to increase:

```
client_max_body_size 4g;
```

But after a restart of the server I get the same error while trying to upload a 6.9Mb file.

Google searches seem to point to increasing "client_max_body_size" but it doesn't seem to work.

here is the nginx.conf

```
    user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {

server{
listen 80;
server_name $host;
client_max_body_size 4g;
client_body_buffer_size 50m;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

I'm at a loss for where to go next. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I think your server `tmp` area is too small. you can check using `df -h` and check for `tmp` partition, how big is it?

Comment: that command shows tmpfs @ 168M with only 396k used.

Comment: Is there a firewall?

Comment: No firewall. Deployed on a ubuntu vm in the cloud.

Comment: Can you try `client_max_body_size 4G;`, `client_body_buffer_size 50M;`

Comment: Just tried it, restarted the server, no change. see my update with the error in the nginx log file. Hopefully it will be helpful.

Comment: Is your form using this `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: <%= form_tag "/my_model", method: :post, class: "dropzone form", :id => "dd-dropzone-"+@model.id.to_s, :multipart => true, :remote => true do %>

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107726/error-upstream-prematurely-closed-connection-while-reading-response-header-from